# Como estruturar uma solução separando WebApi da WebUI usando ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

Como deve ficar organizado uma solução que contará com pelo menos três projetos, sendo eles:

- Class Library como infraestrutura
- Web Application como Web Api
- Web Application MVC para WebUI (interface com usuário)

Onde será utilizado como componente de autenticação e controle de acesso o ASP.NET Identity.

Ou Seja, algo do ASP.NET Identity vai no projeto WebUI (Asp.Net MVC)? O que?

Comment: Você pode customizar o asp.net identity, criando assim um service que atenda esses projetos

Answer (score 2):

A forma que eu uso é:

- `MeuProjeto.Dominio` (Models, Enums, Helpers e Extensions não visuais, ASP.NET Identity);
- `MeuProjeto.MVC` (Controllers, Views);
- `MeuProjeto.WebApi` (ApiControllers).

Tanto o Entity Framework quanto o ASP.NET Identity devem ser instalados no domínio. O ASP.NET Identity deve ser instalado nas aplicações MVC e Web API, pelo menos os pacotes Core e OWIN.

Answer (score 1):

O ideal é isolar seu AspNet Identity do seu projeto principal, pois ele possui responsabilidades e regras que só pertencem à ele e não devem ser misturadas à sua aplicação.

A implementação de AspNet Identity não é uma camada de sua solução, ela faz parte da sua infraestrutura, tendo um "comportamento" de *CrossCutting*.

Eu tenho em meus repositórios do GitHub um exemplo de projeto [WebApi com Identity isolado](https://github.com/thiagolunardi/IdentityIsolation). Ele está completinho, possui até mesmo um projeto web rodando uma aplicação SPA apenas consumindo o WebAPi.

Comment: Isto não é exatamente verdade. O ASP.NET Identity é fortemente acoplado ao Entity Framework. O que se recomenda fazer é utilizar um servidor completamente isolado da solução, e a solução apenas consumir métodos deste servidor. [O IdentityServer é uma dessas implementações](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3).

Comment: Sim, @CiganoMorrisonMendez, eu disse que deve-se isolar o Identity da sua aplicação/solução e não de qualquer outra biblioteca/componente. Vc pode isolar em um projeto só para ela, ou mesmo isolar em um server. Mas, é claro, que não se deve evitar de usar EF. Eu até recomendo EF para Indentity, mesmo se sua aplicação principal optar por outro ORM.

Comment: Ainda assim, sou bastante resistente em acreditar que sua proposta é uma boa ideia. Se eu quiser que meu domínio faça uso das entidades que o ASP.NET Identity gera pra mim (por exemplo, a entidade `ApplicationUser` pode ser relacionada fortemente a outras entidades por FK, por exemplo), faz ainda menos sentido esta separação.

Comment: Bom, você pode fazer isso sim, claro. Eu jamais faria, jamais apoiaria  fazer o domínio depender de uma infraestrutura. Os contextos são diferentes. O domínio da aplicação não deve possuir dados de autenticação, não é responsabilidade dele.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, esqueci de te marcar no comentário acima. :)

Comment: Sinceramente, não sei de onde saiu isso que você falou. Eu nunca vi escrito em lugar algum pela Microsoft, a não ser por algumas pessoas que insistem numas técnicas dessas e que, a meu ver, não representam qualquer ganho de produtividade, segurança ou qualidade de sistema (curiosamente, todos brasileiros). Penso que é alguma moda brasileira esse conceito de *cross-cutting* dentro do ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: O Identity **foi feito** para depender do EF, e portanto, de um domínio, e [você pode escrever outro provedor de armazenamento, se quiser](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity), e é isso. Ele não é um aspecto independente da aplicação. Não é um serviço consumível. Ele é uma arquitetura de autenticação e controle de usuários altamente acoplada ao domínio.

Comment: Não precisa me mencionar. Quando você responde, eu recebo a notificação ;)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44105/discussion-between-thiago-lunardi-and-cigano-morrison-mendez).